# Link fact tables at different granularity levels of a dimension

Tags: data-modeling, data-warehouse

New to data warehouse design. I have a denormalised dimension table representing geographies (e.g. suburb, city, state). This is a slowly changing dimension.

Also have multiple fact tables, each at different grain levels.

Is it possible to model this so the fact tables use surrogate keys, whilst maintaining a denormalised dimension table?

[image: data model]

Comment: You can have a denormalized attributes `city_id` and `suburb_id` in your dimension. You can have the same attributes in your fact tables (also denormalized). But you can't use them as a `FK` as you have no dimension table with them as `PK` (at least in your ER model). You should also define the `dim_geo.id` as `FK` in your fact tables...

Comment: That's what I was worried about. Looks like I'll have to split up `dim_geo` but then how does a user deal with aggregating? If I include a `fact_population.geo_id` as a `FK`, then it works nicely when I use a `GROUP BY` clause. However, for facts at already higher grain levels, it doesn't work as nicely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have effectively the same dimensional data but at different grains then you handle this by creating "aggregate" dimensions. In your example, copy the dim_geo table definition (not the data), name the dim to something like dim_geo_city and drop all the columns at a lower granularity than city (e.g. suburb_id, suburb). If you have facts at the state level then you would create dim_geo_state in the same way - and so on for any further levels of aggregation.

Fact_population will continue to reference dim_geo but fact_housing should reference dim_geo_city.

The easiest way to populate aggregate dims is to run a SELECT DISTINCT on the base dim (dim_geo) and only include the columns that exist in the target dim (dim_geo_city) - you then take the resulting data and apply the appropriate SCD logic to insert/update it into the target dim.

[image]

Comment: So essentially snowflaking the `dim_geo`

Comment: No, not at all. Snowflaking involves relating Dims to each other, this is relating geographic Dims at different granularities to different fact tables

Comment: I see now. Thanks for explaining and the diagram. Really helped.