# Multiple fact tables for each grain level

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse

Following up from this [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66009165/link-fact-tables-at-different-granularity-levels-of-a-dimension). How do you best model a set of facts that don't aggregate? For example a "score" for each city, each state, and each electorate. However the city scores don't add up equal the state scores, so they're independent.

Would this be an appropriate way to organise them in a data warehouse? Should I look to combine them in some other way?

Business questions being asked are:

- How does X city's score compare with Y city's score?
- Give me all the city's that score a 3 and tell me some other facts about them (e.g. population, gender)
- Show me the overall state score and how the cities within that state score

[image: diagram]

Comment: Fact tables must have a declared grain and you should only include measures in that fact table that are aligned to the grain

Comment: If the *score* is an attribute of the *city* you should keep it there *in the city dimension*. If the *score* changes over time you have a `SCD`.

Comment: ahh I hadn't considered storing it in the dimension. That might make more sense. In that case, would I store a `city_score`, `state_score`, and `country_score` in the one `dim_city` dimension?

Comment: In which dimension we can find population, gender ?

Comment: @SandraGuilepZouaouiZandeh - didn't put that in the diagram cos it's just an example, but population and gender numbers would be in another fact table